# Make several columns using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

The below code (calculation of moving average over N-days) works for well. But I want to replace other numbers (e.g., 5, 10, 20, etc.) with 50. Not sure if I can turn the below code into something in for loop. Could anybody please help me?

```
df['ma50pfret']= df['ret']

df.loc[df.adjp >= df.ma50, 'adjp > ma50']= 1
df.loc[df.adjp < df.ma50, 'adjp > ma50']= 0
df.iloc[0, -1]= 1

df['adjp > ma50']= df['adjp > ma50'].astype(int)
df.loc[df['adjp > ma50'].shift(1)== 0, 'ma50pfret']= 1.000079 # 1.02**(1/250)

df['cum_ma50pfret']=df['ma50pfret'].cumprod()
df.head(10)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input and preferred output for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just mean to replace the 50's with 5, 10, 20, etc? If so, that could be done by always using brackets to access columns, and using f-strings (or some other string formatting method) to replace 50 with the other numbers, like this:

```
for num in [5, 10, 20, 50]:
    df[f'ma{num}pfret']= df['ret']

    df.loc[df.adjp >= df[f'ma{num}'], f'adjp > ma{num}']= 1
    df.loc[df.adjp < df[f'ma{num}], f'adjp > ma{num}']= 0
    df.iloc[0, -1]= 1

    df[f'adjp > ma{num}']= df[f'adjp > ma{num}'].astype(int)
    df.loc[df[f'adjp > ma{num}'].shift(1)== 0, f'ma{num}pfret']= 1.000079 # 1.02**(1/250)

    df[f'cum_ma{num}pfret']=df[f'ma{num}pfret'].cumprod()

df.head(10)
```